# ENCODING_ERR when trying to access the external storage card

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-external-storage

From a cordova-android based app I'm trying to read the contents stored in an external sdcard (that is, a removable card).
By using the `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` plugin I've managed to get the path to the sdcard. These details are:

```
file:///storage/75FF-1911
file:///storage/75FF-1911/Android/data/es. ... .myAppName/files
```

By using the `cordova-plugin-file` plugin I'm trying to read the contents stored in the root of the sdcard but I'm getting a `ENCODING_ERR` when calling the `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` method. The code I'm using is the one that follows:

```
url = "file:///storage/75FF-1911";
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(url, onSuccessResolveLocalFileSystemURL, onError);

onSuccessResolveLocalFileSystemURL : function(directoryEntry) {    
//never called    
}    

onError : function(fileError) {
    var msg = "";

    console.log("onError():called");

    switch (fileError.code) {
    ...
    case FileError.ENCODING_ERR: // 5
    msg = 'ENCODING_ERR';
    break;
    ...
    }    
    console.log("onError():" + fileError.code + " - " + msg);
}
```

When the app gets executed I allways get this trace:

```
onError():called
onError():5 - ENCODING_ERR
```

I don't understand why the `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL()` method of the `cordova-plugin-file` plugin fails when I pass to it a string containing a path that has been got from the `getExternalSdCardDetails()` method of the `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` plugin.

What exactly does the `ENCODING_ERR` error mean? It seems that this path doesn't exist.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For those facing the some problem just to know that it's required to include these two lines in the `config.xml` file, as it's set out [here](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6359):

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
```

However, in my `config.xml` file it was enough to set `"sdcard,cache"` values for the `AndroidExtraFilesystems` preference, that is:

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />
```

The **problem I had** was that my IDE somehow included those preference entries in a `config.xml` file hold in `$(My_PROJECT)\platforms\android\res\xml`.

After deleting those lines in this second `config.xml` file, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileError

From this link we can see :

```
ENCODING_ERR    5   The URL is malformed. Make sure that the URL is complete and valid.
```

I think your URL is bad because you don't have the rights to access the storage.

Did you have this into you'r config.xml ?

```
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="sdcard,cache" />
```

Into one of my cordova project in production i used a function for test the access before every read/write like this :

```
AskForAutorizationStatus: function(onSuccess, onError) {
    var me = this;

    // If it is on iOS, do not ask for authorization
    if (Ext.platformTags.ios) {
        Ext.Function.bind(onSuccess, me).call(me);
    }
    else {        
        // Request for authorization
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestExternalStorageAuthorization((status) => {
            cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getExternalStorageAuthorizationStatus((status) => {
                // if authorization ok
                if(status === cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED){
                    Ext.Function.bind(onSuccess, me).call(me);
                }
                else {
                    Ext.Function.bind(onError, me).call(me);
                }
            }, () => {});
        }, () => {});
    }
}
```

It's a ExtJS code so don't worry if syntax seems strange.

I hope I helped you, don't hesitate if you have any further questions

Comment: thanks for your reply. My URL wasn't malformed but you are right when saying that it's needed to include a _preference_ directive in the `config.xml` file. I've just posted how I solved the problem I had.